# getRestApiId function in objects from office-js for OneNote

Tags: office-js, office-addins, onenote, onenote-api

I'm developing add-in for OneNote and I've had trouble use OneNote REST APIs, as office-js doesn't give ID compatible with REST APIs. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491066/difference-between-notebook-id-by-officejs-and-onenote-api)  [UserVoice](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/17010982-add-onenote-add-ins-to-onenote-api-compatible-ids)
And as I know that the ID from office-js is not unique, I had to retrieve data from REST API using clientUrl to get the unique ID and it took around 5-6 secs per each call. It was our big issue and couldn't find any workaround for this.

But after a few months, I just found there is a function named `getRestApiId` in objects from office-js and surprisingly it works perfect in my tests. I'm not sure this is added recently and maybe not ready to use, or it was there. I can't find any information about this.
Could anyone confirm whether it's good to use or still under developing?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: We now support "GetRestApi" and it have documented it

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/onenote/page.md#getRestApiId

---

OLD: You'll find that it doesn't work for all types of accounts (only Office365 accounts) - which is why this isn't publicly documented. We do plan to make it work for all types of accounts soon.

Comment: Despite this being effectively a work-around, this is great to know! You should probably do a Dev blog post on it. Maybe adding a post on how to use the REST API concurrently with the Add-In would be helpful. For example, do I have to "double authenticate" to use the API?